# Is it possible to access files of a service launched on HANA XS cockpit in order to build a deployable MTAR file out of it?

Tags: git, sap, sap-hana

Consider a scenario: a developer maintains a HANA project in WebIDE, instantiates it as a service in DEV environment, accidentally forgets to check their code into GIT, and leaves on a well deserved vacation. Another developer needs to promote that HANA component into a higher environment and needs either the source code or the MTAR file. Is it possible to access the files that comprise the service that is running in DEV and build the transportable MTAR file? If so, how can the files be accessed and what can be used to build that MTAR ?